# Alignment issues in placing the close button in dialog in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place the close button in the right most top corner of the dialog.However i have given the required attributes.It is not aligning properly.When viewing in the xml it is perfectly right.But it is not aligned to the right most in the emulator.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
<!--  Header Inclusion -->
<include
    android:id="@+id/pheader"
    layout="@layout/playheader"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp" >
</include>
<!-- Header Inclusion -->
<!--  Dialog Layout For Reading -->
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/readscroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textviewlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.08"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#6D6968">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:text="Provide Overall Effectivness of the speech"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="@drawable/roundedlayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/readtext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="134dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<!--  Dialog Layout For Reading -->
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the layout for `android:id="@+id/pheader"` include? As I believe the button is in a layout that spans wider than you expect.

Comment: Header Layout <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/playheader">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/closeinheader"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
android:src="@drawable/close" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: You should edit the question and add there the layout :P

Comment: Since you have a dialog there, then this is the result you should have. The dialog doesn't take the full width and height. If you want to have a full screen on top, use a transparent activity instead.

Comment: To confirm my statement, can you put a colored background in the root `RelativeLayout`? You will see what dimension it occupies.

Comment: Ok i will put and will give you the screen shot

Comment: Yes you are right.I have changed what you said.It is working fine

Comment: Which of my statements help? :)

Comment: first upvoted comment

Answer (score 1):

change your relative layout from this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
```

to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>
```

I create one playheader file as per your need as below:

**playheader.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

     >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and now my view is like this:

[image]

Try this. hope it will help.